# I want to apply the changes Filter_Default.html (selectedfilters & unselectedfilters array)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, refiner, refinement-panel

Instead of V1,V2,V3 ,i want to show the refiner values as
V1
V2
V3

I tried to do changes in Filter_multivalue.html and it worked.

But in my requirement, i want to implement in Filter_Default.html.

Please share the code for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Allow Multiple value" of refinement managed property in Search schema as shown below:
[image]

Filter_multivalue.html and Filter_Default.html will both show value as separate value.

Difference between both display template is that Multi-value Refinement Item template has a check box next to each refiner.

Reference:

Display templates for the Refinement Web Part and the Taxonomy Refinement Web Part

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/display-template-reference-in-sharepoint-server#display-templates-for-the-refinement-web-part-and-the-taxonomy-refinement-web-part